# Adding query string to response redirect ASP VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, query-string, response.redirect

I'm trying to add the value from my query string to a response redirect. I've added my code below, any help would be great.

```
If Boolean.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("Development")) Then
            If Request.QueryString("ABC") = "Y" Then
                Session("Website") = "abc"
            End If  
            If Not Request.QueryString("LOCATION") = "" Then
                Response.Redirect "mysite.co.uk/location/" & Request.QueryString("LOCATION")
            End If          
        End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when you use:

```
Response.Redirect("http://mysite.co.uk/location/" & Request.QueryString("LOCATION"))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Response.Redirect("Yourpage.aspx?UserId="+location);
```